# Redux action creator finishes, update subscribed component

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs

I have a component for properties on my page. It opens in a modal, and changes properties in redux store, most notably a number of items to display in search results. I also have a component called Search, which basically uses the redux store to update itself. What I am wrestling with is, I need to know when the action creator for number of items is finished, notifying my search it has completed this action, so I can execute search with the new number of items variable.

In the past I would use componentWillRecieveProps and just check for the change, but that has gone away in favor of getDerivedStateFromProps. This appears to be one way I can go, but I also thought about using RXJS to call observables, but I cannot see any examples that do what I am specifically trying to accomplish (a notification that an action creator is complete). Anyone have this same issue? Which method is better road to tread, RXJS vs getDerivedStateFromProps? I am also using redux-thunk, but I cannot see a way to tie in a subscription to an action creator in any way. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sample Code
Action Creator:

```
export function setNumRecords(val){
    return dispatch => {
        localStorage.setItem('numRecords', val);
        dispatch({type: 'SET_NUM_RECORDS', numRecords:val})
    };
}
```

When the dispatch is complete I want Search component to update. I am not sure how much more code is needed.

Comment: as i understand, is the searchResultCount is a prop sent to the search box , which is used as its state in its constructor ?

Comment: Search Component is a connected component, so it is aware of the changes in prop from redux in searchResultCount. But it does not have a way of knowing when the action creator is finished outside of checking getDerivedStateFromProps. It just feels dirty, I feel using some sort of listener would be better. But I cannot find anything.

Comment: If you can post some sample code ...

Comment: @Anas - I added the action creator. Not really sure what you are looking for to give the right information. I need the action creator to be listened to by the Search Component, once finished I can call getSearchResults in another actionCreator to get the values needed in redux.

Comment: I might be able to pass details into my Preferences about the search we are currently on, then call the actionCreator for update search results whenever searchResultCount is updated, but that is doubling up my action calls. May work, because I do always want that updated whenever searchResultCount is changed.

Comment: You can use redux-observable (RxJS), listen to `SET_NUM_RECORDS` then fire your search.

Comment: That was what I was wondering, but I couldn't find any examples of how to set that up. Got a resource you can point me to @Anas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup redux observable as a middleware in your app:

https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/SettingUpTheMiddleware.html

Then in your root epic, you can listen to your action:

```
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import {
  tap,
  mapTo,
} from 'rxjs/operators';

const setNumRecordsEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType('SET_NUM_RECORDS'),
    tap(() => console.log('Here...'))
    mapTo({ type: 'SOME_OTHER_ACTION' })
);
```

Comment: this code would be inside my Search component? Also what implications would that middleware have on like redux-thunk? Or should I replace redux-thunk with this? Hoping not to refactor all of the actions I have currently with thunk.

Comment: That won't have any impact on your existing redux-thunk actions, you can use both middlewares. You can create a separate file for your redux-observable epics. Note that if you don't have any RxJS knowledge, it won't be easy to use redux-observable, there is a learning curve. Here is a sample app, that you can check on how to use redux-observable: https://github.com/alaa0000/sieve-of-eratosthenes/tree/master/web-app/src

Comment: I still don't see from the example code how to link it up to a component in my project. The components in the main project don't have anything to do with the middleware calls? I am still thoroughly confused. Onto more tutorials.

Comment: just watched the video on redux-observable - seems like I was missing the idea that it is actions in and actions out. So all of this happens inside the single middleware file. Makes more sense now.